# SOQL result of a field value to be assigned to a variable

Tags: salesforce, apex

How to fetch single field value from this query

```
String query='Select Title,Question__c,Answer__c,Summary, TestField__c From Know__kav Where Articlenumber = '----';
```

Need summary value in a variable?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean... are you querying for a single record? where you will have the value of the summary field in a variable or a list of records where you will have a list of summary field values in a variable. 
If its the first you can just use a SOQL query with dot notation to assign the field to a value eg. (This is assuming the type of 'summary' field is String)

```
String summary = [SELECT Title,Question__c,Answer__c,Summary,TestField__c From Know__kav Where Articlenumber = '----' LIMIT 1].Summary;
```

And if it's the other I think you would need to loop through the results of the query and assign all the values of that field to a new List for example...

```
Know__kav queryResult = [Select Title,Question__c,Answer__c,Summary, TestField__c From Know__kav Where Articlenumber = '----'];
List<String> summaryList = new List<String>();
for(Know__kav k : queryResult){
    summaryList.add(k.summary);
} //Now you have all the values of summary in one list.
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the summary is a string type.
The query is

```
List<Know__kav> knowkaves = [Select Title,Question__c,Answer__c,Summary, TestField__c From Know__kav Where Articlenumber = '----'];
```

If you know, it returns a single row then

```
String Summary = null;
if(knowkaves.size(0 > 0)
{
    Summary = knowkaves[0].Summary;
}
```

else, you have many summaries, right. Then you can save it in a List.

```
List<String> Summaries = new List<String>();
if(knowkaves.size() > 0)
{
    for(Know__kav k : knowkaves){
       Summaries.add(k.summary);
    } 
}
```